# three.js cordova apk for android

Tags: javascript, cordova, three.js

I'm developed simple 3D android app using cordova and three.js. Its is not working on few device(HTC one X, Samsung S6) and works perfectly in few device(ASUS, One + one). I have no idea why it is not working and It is showing blank white screen. Here is my js code

```
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    $('#wrapper').html(renderer.domElement);
    element = renderer.domElement;
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    var effect = new THREE.StereoEffect(renderer);
    effect.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    var axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(70000.5);
    //scene.add(axis);
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 2.5, 4, 2.5 ), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
    cube.position.z=-4;
    scene.add( cube );
    var lastTimeMsec = null;
    function animate(timestamp) {
    effect.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    animate();
```

Can any one please let me know the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A lot of Android devices have their own bugs that show up only for specific hardware and specific software. While the error seems the same the causes can be different. You probably have to debug your exact problem for each phone seperatly

Answer (score 1):

We need to install one cordova plugin(cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
) before build. This allows three.js to support all the device.

Comment: Not all devices. Especially when the Android version is lower than 5.0. Check the [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37737121/6858891) and the [Crosswalk website](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html#Canvas-and-WebGL-support).